# How do I insert records into 2 SQL tables sharing a dependency when I don't commit until the end?

Tags: sql, transactions

I keep finding myself in this situtation:

I have an ASP.NEt 2.0 app. I have to insert into 2 tables in SQL. There is a dependency between the tables. I insert a record the first using a transaction. Then I move onto the 2nd table. But, because the first isn't committed yet the second one throws a error.

Comment: You should be doing both of these within the same transaction?

Comment: to the `vote to close as not a real question person`, did you read the title? **How do I insert records into 2 SQL tables sharing a dependency when I don’t commit until the end?**

Comment: You aren't doing both inserts in the SAME transaction. If you were, this wouldn't happen. Within a transaction, it isn't necessary to commit to satisfy constraints.

Answer (score 2):

You must not be using the same connection when you modify each table.  Try using the same connection and a single transaction around all of your changes to both tables.  When in a transaction you see your changes and no one else will see them (unless they force dirty reads) until you COMMIT them.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create a STORED PROCEDURE?
In this way, with A SINGLE transaction you invoke the STORED PROCEDURE, that makes first the INSERT into the parent table, and then (inside the same transaction) inserts into the child table.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE GOOFY
IS
BEGIN
INSERT INTO MY_PARENT_TABLE VALUES (1111, 'ALPHA');
INSERT INTO MY_CHILD_TABLE VALUES (1111, 'BETA');
END;
/
```

All you have to do is to invoke GOOFY from ASP.NET 2.0: the two INSERTS belong to the same transaction, and you can decide to COMMIT or ROLLBACK.